# JeringTech Javascript.NodeJS with Azure Linux NodeJS path error

Tags: node.js, azure

I have an app which works fine locally but when I try going to a specific page on my Azure hosted site I get an error.

Error:

```
[1] Ensure that NodeJS is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories. The current PATH enviroment variable is: /opt/dotnetcore-tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/site/wwwroot. Make sure that the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] Refer to the InnerException for further details. No such file or directory 

Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.ConnectionException:
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.OutOfProcessNodeJSService.ConnectIfNotConnected (Jering.Javascript.NodeJS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3786d24ab42c57d6)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.OutOfProcessNodeJSService+<TryInvokeCoreAsync>d__42`1.MoveNext (Jering.Javascript.NodeJS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3786d24ab42c57d6)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.OutOfProcessNodeJSService+<InvokeFromStringAsync>d__31`1.MoveNext (Jering.Javascript.NodeJS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3786d24ab42c57d6)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at ImageGenMvc.Controllers.HomeController+<LoadImage>d__14.MoveNext (Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /home/runner/work/test/Controllers/HomeController.cs:146)
Inner exception System.InvalidOperationException handled at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.OutOfProcessNodeJSService.ConnectIfNotConnected:
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.NodeJSProcessFactory.CreateProcess (Jering.Javascript.NodeJS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3786d24ab42c57d6)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.NodeJSProcessFactory.Create (Jering.Javascript.NodeJS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3786d24ab42c57d6)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.OutOfProcessNodeJSService.CreateAndSetUpProcess (Jering.Javascript.NodeJS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3786d24ab42c57d6)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.OutOfProcessNodeJSService.ConnectIfNotConnected (Jering.Javascript.NodeJS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3786d24ab42c57d6)
Inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception handled at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.NodeJSProcessFactory.CreateProcess:
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess (System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore (System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.NodeJSProcessFactory.CreateProcess (Jering.Javascript.NodeJS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3786d24ab42c57d6)
```

If I Bash at https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/ I get:

```
/home>node -v
v14.18.2
/home>whereis node
node: /usr/local/bin/node /opt/nodejs/14.17.6/bin/node /opt/nodejs/9.4.0/bin/node
/home>
```

So the error says the current path is
/usr/local/bin

And Bash says node exists in
/usr/local/bin/node

So why can't it find Node?